# Oledb connection providing garbage values while reading from excel

Tags: c#, excel, date, oledb

I am having a date type column in excel file. When I am trying to read the values from excel using `OLEDB` command, some garbage values are being inserted in data table. For example, if the data in excel date column is 0-Jan=00 it is reading as 31-12-1899 12:00:00 AM. How can it be avoided or read the same value into data table?

Note: Other than that one all the other date values are reading properly.

This is the connection string I am using for it.

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + 
                   fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
```